# Does Objective-C compile to native code or byte-code?

Tags: objective-c, linux, cocoa, macos

On OS X, does Objective-C compile to native code or byte-code?

Can Objective-C programs be compiled on Linux?

Comment: If you ever "step in" too far, you'll see the assembly interpretation of the machine code being executed!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Objective-C is compiled to native code by either GCC or LLVM[*].  You can compile ObjC programs on Linux (the generic GCC will happily support ObjC, though it uses a different runtime library than either of the Apple ones). For a cross-platform API similar to Cocoa (i.e. derived from Cocoa) which will happily work on Linux and let you port some code between OS X and Linux, check out GNUstep: http://www.gnustep.org

[*]In fact, LLVM internally compiles the Objective-C to an internal bitcode representation, then to code for the target machine, so perhaps the answer is "both"…

Comment: To clarify, for 'LLVM' read 'GCC using the LLVM back-end'. LLVM on it's own is not a compiler but a back-end machine-code generator.

Comment: Apple is working on clang, a front-end to LLVM; GCC is not used at all in this path.  It's not ready for production usage yet, though.

Comment: Also, Cocoa would be more accurately described as being derived from GNUStep (OpenStep) than the other way around.

Comment: @marcin Cocoa is a marketing term for Apple's OpenStep implementation[*], and GNUstep is derived from OpenStep…
[*] a non-compliant implementation as it lacks the DPS functions ;-)

Comment: Cocoa is in no way derived from GNUstep.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to cross-compile from Mac OS X to Windows or Linux, check out Cocotron.

Answer (score 7):

It's native.

There is [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/information/aboutGNUstep.html) which an Open Source implementation of the NeXT OpenStep specification written in Objective-C. Their implementation of the Cocoa API is not a direct match so a direct compilation without porting is not possible.

Comment: To give a nice update 7 years later; GNUStep does a pretty damn good job at mirroring OpenStep/Cocoa at this point in time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Objective-C compiles to machine code.

Objective-C compilers exist for Linux, but Cocoa is an OS X-only technology. I've heard of an open replacement called GNUstep, but don't know much about it.

Comment: I used to work as a GNUstep developer - still have the SVN commit flag but haven't actually done so in a while. It's a nice system and provides a good amount of source compatibility with Cocoa, but you'd be misguided if you thought that you could just take an arbitrary Mac app and type 'make'.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a variant of C. It compiles to native code.

Comment: Note that this allows for deliciously dirty things such as using naked C or C++ code in the middle of your Objective-C programs!