# Does every Objective C program get converted to C code?

Tags: objective-c, c

Since Objective-C is basically an extension of C, Does the code get converted to pure C code before it is compiled to native code ?

If so, does the conversion happens on RAM or a temporary  file containing C code on disk is created by the compiler which is further compiled by C compiler to native code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Objective-C compile to native code or byte-code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172614/does-objective-c-compile-to-native-code-or-byte-code)

Comment: No. because I know that There is no VM with JIT and Obj C code compiles to bytecode.
Please read the my comment in response to larsmans answer.

Comment: But the answers are have to be the same as they have to tell you how the code is compiled

Comment: Sorry,
Actually While I was answering your question, I didnt read their answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That Objective-C *syntax* is an extension of C syntax does not mean that it could not have its own compiler. C++ is the same way - its syntax is compatible with C (for the most part, anyway) but it has its own set of tools. Compilers for C, C++, and Objective-C can reuse parts of each other for preprocessing, syntactic analysis and code generation, but there is not need to run them sequentially (e.g. Objective-C ==> C ==> Target code). Compilers no longer go through human-readable assembly language, either (this has been the case for a very long time, too).

Answer (score 4):

No, Objective-C gets compiled to assembler directly (assuming GCC).

Comment: but there should be some reason for which classes in Objective C are implemented as C structures.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: what do you mean by that?

Comment: If you look at Apple's documentation, objects of Classes in Objective C are basically  pointers to some C Structures. for eg id is actually typedef for objc_obj*.

and that structure has an isa pointer telling which class it belongs  to and other info about it.

So if everything is coming down to pure C code, Does it get converted as an intermediate C code may be in memory if not on disk ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: the memory representation of classes may be the same as that of C structures, but there's no intermediate C code being generated. The C, C++ and Objective-C compilers in GCC are quite intricately linked, but all generate assembler "directly".